# Basis for set of nxn matrices with trace = 0

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find a basis for the set of all $n \times n$ matrices with trace $0$.  I know that part of that basis will be matrices with $1$ in only one entry and $0$ for all others for entries outside the diagonal, as they are not relevant.

I don't understand though how to generalize for the entries on the diagonal.  Maybe just one matrix with $1$ in the $(1, 1)$ position and a $-1$ in all other $n - 1$ positions?

Comment: A basis is far from a *unique* object, so you can't say what the basis *must* have in it.  That said, there's a nice basis made of particularly sparse matrices along the lines of what you have described.

Comment: I really don't know what to make out of your comment.

Comment: You speak of **the** basis as if there is only one, but we could come up with all sorts of different bases of the space.  I've described one possible basis in the answers below, in which the matrices are quite sparse (they are mostly zeroes).

Comment: Ok thank you. I had understood the fact there can be more than one basis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to finish constructing your basis, you could add the set of matrices for which the $(1,1)$ entry is $1$, the $(i,i)$ entry is $-1$ for some $i \neq 1$, and all other entries are zero.

Note that the space of $n\times n$ matrices with trace $0$ is $n^2 - 1$ dimensional, so you should have this many elements in your basis in total.

Answer (score 11):

The *matrix unit* $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with $1$ in the $(i, j)$-entry and $0$ everywhere else.  A basis for your space consists is
$$
\{ E_{ij} \; \mid \; i \ne j \} \cup \{ E_{ii} - E_{i+1, i+1} \; \mid \; 1 \le i < n \}.
$$

Notice that there are $n(n-1)$ of the off diagonal matrices and $n-1$ of the diagonal ones, for a total of $n^2 - 1$ matrices.  This is the right size set since your space is the null space of the onto map
$$
\operatorname{tr}: \Bbb{R}^{n^2} \to \Bbb{R}.
$$

Comment: Can you extend a little bit more about how did you get this idea??

Answer (score 4):

Since you have to find the dimension of the subspace of all matrices whose trace is $0$, having a linear transformation T: $M(n×n)→ ℝ$, all it really comes down to is finding the size of *ker(T)*.

In order to do so, notice that the standard matrix for the given transformation will have the dimension $1$ × $n^2$. Hence, applying Gauss Jordan, we get only one pivot variable and $n^2-1$ free variables. Since the number of free variables gives us the nullity of T (dimension of the kernel), and it is equal to the dimension of the subspace we're looking for, dimension of all *n* × *n* matrices with zero trace is simply $n^2-1$.

Then you can figure out what the actual basis could look like.

Answer (score 1):

Note that trace equals zero says that the $n,n$ term is given by the remaining. So start with the usual basis with 
$$
A_{k,m}=1, ~~~  (k,m) \ne (n,n),\\ A_{i, j} = 0 , ~~~~(i,j) \ne (k, m), \\
A_{n,n} = -\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} A_{i,i}$$

Thus the basis has $n^2-1$ elements.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the subspace $W = \{ A \in M_{n \times n}(F) : tr(A) = 0\} = \{ A \in M_{n \times n}(F) : \sum_{i=1}^{n} A_{ii} = 0\}.$ Now, we apply the standard representation of $M_{n \times n}(F)$ with respect to the matrix units $\beta,$ which is an isomorphism $\phi_{\beta}$ from $M_{n \times n}(F)$ onto $F^{n^{2}}.$ Namely, we express each element of $W$ as a coordinate vector relative to $\beta,$ i.e.,
$$\phi_{\beta}(W) = \{ (A_{11},A_{12},\dots,A_{21},A_{22},\dots,A_{nn}) \in F^{n^{2}} : \sum_{i=1}^{n} A_{ii} = 0\}.$$

Next, we encode the linear constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{n} A_{ii} = 0$ into the following matrix
$$B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 1\end{pmatrix},$$
since the solution set of the corresponding homogeneous system:
$$B \begin{pmatrix} A_{11} \\ A_{12} \\ \vdots \\ A_{21} \\ A_{22} \\ \vdots \\ A_{nn} \end{pmatrix} = 0$$
satisfies the constraint. Now, we identify the solution set as the null space $N(B),$ then we apply the dimension theorem ($dim(N(B)) = nullity(B) = dim(F^{n^{2}}) - rank(B)$). Thus, the problem is to find a subset of the null space with exactly $n^{2} - 1$ linearly independent vectors.

To obtain this subset, we identify the $B_{11} = 1$ entry as the pivot variable. Next, we identify the remaining entries as the free variables. Then, we obtain a solution
$$\{ (0,1,\dots,0,0,\dots,0),\dots, (-1,0,\dots,0,1,\dots,0),\dots,(-1,0,\dots,0,0,\dots,1)\},$$
where we have expressed the vectors as $n^{2}$-tuples. Lastly, we apply the inverse of the standard representation $\phi_{\beta}^{-1}$ to the solution in order to return square matrices instead of coordinate vectors.